# What is the meaning of the Chinese symbol that Oogway uses to attack Kai?

Tags: analysis, kung-fu-panda-3

I've been studying Mandarin lately, and I recently watched Kung Fu Panda 3. In the opening scene between Oogway and Kai, Oogway uses a Chinese symbol to attack Kai. Does anyone know what the symbol means?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The chinese character is [氣](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chi#English) which means:

> (philosophy) A life force in traditional Chinese philosophy, culture, medicine, etc. related (but not limited) to breath and circulation.

It is pronounced as /tʃiː/ and its alternative forms are ki or [qi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qi).

As explained in the linked [Wikipedia article on Chinese martial arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_martial_arts), harnessing 'qi' is primary focus in practicing Kung Fu. The article states:

> There are styles that mimic movements from animals and others that gather inspiration from various Chinese philosophies, myths and legends. Some styles put most of their focus into the harnessing of **qi**, while others concentrate on competition.